# Get cell color via Excel Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, javascript-api-for-office

In Ms articles they [describe how to **set** the Excel cell color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-special-cells) via JavaScript API.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    let usedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
    let formulaRanges = usedRange.getSpecialCells(Excel.SpecialCellType.formulas);
    formulaRanges.format.fill.color = "pink";

    await context.sync();
});
```

However, is not really clear, how to **get** that color. There is any "fill" field when I load the "format"

```
format: Object
autoIndent: false
columnWidth: 19.5
horizontalAlignment: "Left"
indentLevel: 3
readingOrder: "Context"
rowHeight: 18
shrinkToFit: false
textOrientation: 0
useStandardHeight: true
useStandardWidth: true
verticalAlignment: "Center"
wrapText: false
```

That is nowhere in documentation samples, as usual in MS poor docs...
By testing and guessing I could achieve this:

```
  let rangeFill = range.format.fill;
  rangaeFill.load(["color"])

  await context.sync();
  console.log("range.format.fill.color", rangeFill.color)
```

However, the open question remains if there are some conditional formatting applied, how to get the final color? Because this color is one if no conditional formatting applied.